# How to link existing project files in TFS to a new solution in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a solution under which there are 15 projects. This solution is on TFS. I want to create another solution in the same directory in TFS, however I want to use only 12 out of the 15 projects. Which means I don't want to duplicate the projects, but just selectively link a few of them to this second solution.

What I tried was to create a new solution on my local machine and add those projects from my checked out version and just move the .sln file over to TFS. But this didn't work when building on the server, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0):

You will have better luck of you make the solution in the same folder as the other solution in your workspace.

Then add the projects and get it to build locally. You should then be able to add the solution to source inplace and build from it.